# Tips and best practices for bumping out pantry into garage

Tags: electrical, drywall, doors, framing

How can I effectively expand our kitchen storage by creating a small walk-in pantry above the basement stairwell in the garage?

I've successfully added an exterior window to a wood-paneled wall, providing access to the stud wall for support. However, I'm uncertain about cutting into the drywall and modifying it for a door. I'm considering a narrower door, and I anticipate the need to relocate the kitchen outlet and garage lamp.

The width between the garage drywall on the left and the outer edge of the stairwell block wall on the right measures 55 inches, which is roughly the maximum width for the pantry (including framing). Any advice or tips from someone with experience in a similar project would be greatly appreciated. I've searched online for videos but haven't found a suitable guide yet.

Here's the kitchen wall:

[image: Kitchen wall]

And here's the opposite wall in the garage:

[image: Garage wall above stairwell]

Comment: It does not look like you could extend the kitchen floor into the garage very much, or at all, without creating a head-room problem on the staircase.  Certainly not enough to make it worthwhile building a walk-in closet that requires a structural floor.  Instead, create a bump-out pantry.    Its bottom can be above the level of the outlet and lantern, it can be 20 or 24 inches deep with pullout shelves.  The framing does not have to be designed to support people.  The lantern can remain, and will light up the stairs beneath the bump-out.

Comment: @jay613 That's not a bad solution if that is all that would be possible - however those existing boards do not create a headroom problem so I don't see an issue with a pantry at least that deep. According to some quick research, code requires 80 inches of clearance above the tip of the nosing, and with the dimensions of that stairway that would allow a pantry 2.5 to 3 feet deep.

Comment: Sounds like you're thinking the right way.  It's not impossible, I just think the extra cost and effort gives you not much more functionality.  In your 80 inch calculations are you allowing for a floor that is level with the kitchen, has about an inch of flooring, 10 inch joists and half inch of ceiling beneath that?  And if the whole space is about 48  wide and 36 deep and you put 16 inch shelves on 3 walls, your "walk in" space is only about 18x20 inches!

Comment: @jay613 That's a very good point! It sounds like I should take the time to draw up some plans and find how much usable space I have to work with. I really like your idea of a bump-out pantry, it could be plenty spacious and I don't have to worry about electrical.

Comment: Major thing is to construct the walls (and exposed to garage space floor) appropriately - common for the wall between living space and garage space to need a higher level/standard of fireproofing than the average residential wall. Insulate well if you don't heat the garage

Comment: Couple things to think about: is this a load bearing wall? (Rough rule of thumb: load bearing if it runs perpendicular to joists and rafters.) If you are unlucky, the electrical might go up, rather than down. (Not a showstopper, but adds a bit of work.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Yes, this is load bearing. I expect to have to move a good portion of drywall to access the header for support during construction. I also suspect the electrical goes up, but I am not sure. Jay613 above mentioned constructing the pantry above the outlet, but for extra space I may go ahead and move the electrical so I can have a full vertical door. I have attic access to electrical access is possible, just more effort of course. EDIT: This wall is parallel to the gable end of the roof above, so it may not be load bearing. I have to double check the joists.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I've heard this, so I'm accounting for fire rated drywall and extra insulation in my plan.

Comment: @jay613   I thought the fix for low headroom on stairs was to put up a picture of a duck.